# JavaScript push to subkey

Tags: javascript

I have the following array: `vm.posts.items`

How can I push data into a subkey? This doesn't work:

```
vm.posts.items[arrayid].comment.push = response.plain();
```

### More Informations:

This is the addComment Function (the console.log match to the data structures below):

```
function addComment(comment, arrayid, postid) {
            var commentObj = {
                text: comment,
                post: postid
            };
            dsActivity.addComment(commentObj)
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(arrayid);
                    console.log(response.plain());
                    console.log(vm.posts.items);
                    console.log(vm.posts.items[arrayid]);
                    vm.posts.items[arrayid].comment.push(response.plain());
                    console.log(vm.posts.items[arrayid]);
                }.bind(arrayid));
        }
```

### Data Structure:

arrayid: `1`

response:

`_embedded: Object
_links: Object
createdAt: Object
id: 91
resource: Object
text: "test"
__proto__: Object`

vm.posts.items (only one opened):
`0: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
5: Object
6: Object
7: Object
8: Object
9: Object
  $$hashKey: "object:48"
  _embedded: Object
  _links: Array[0]
  comment: Object
  __proto__: Object
  createdAt: Object
  id: 42
  resource: Object
  text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
  total_comments: 0
  __proto__: Object`

vm.posts.items[arrayid]:
`$$hashKey: "object:41"
_embedded: Object
_links: Array[0]
comment: Object
commentFormVisible: true
commentform: "test"
createdAt: Object
id: 134
resource: Object
text: "f"
total_comments: 0
__proto__: Object`

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: comment doesn't need push, you are doing a direct assignment to the object at the specified key in vm.posts.items[arrayid]

Comment: @Simon I updated my answer, check if it works for your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`push` is a function present in the prototype of `Array`, you should do as follows:

```
vm.posts.items[arrayid].comment.push(response.plain());
```

Assuming that when you do `vm.posts.items[arrayid].comment` you get an array, but without the structure of your data or more code it's difficult to provide the solution that best suits your issues.

As per the code you've added, Could'nt you just do:

```
vm.posts.items[arrayid].comment = response;
```

As per your comments, you might consider adding a `comments` property to your data, an array where you can push your comments:

```
 vm.posts.items[arrayid].comments = vm.posts.items[arrayid].comments || [];
 vm.posts.items[arrayid].comments.push(response.plain());
```

Comment: This doesn't work, 

vm.posts.items[arrayid].comment.push is not a function

Comment: You will have to provide more info in that case.

Comment: I've provided more info in my question

Comment: It's not possible to just assign commentObj, because the user and datetime is being set by the api and included in the callback

Comment: Sorry, edited. Just say your console.log of the response.

Comment: the plain() is from Restangular Service, this is not the problem. But it's working now. Sorry maybe I didnt implement it correct at first.

The comment Object is in the subkey comment. But I need an array instead of one comment object (multiple comments as array). Isn't push the right method?

Comment: yes, push is the right way to go, i've edited my answer.

Comment: Okay. But there's still this error appearing in the console:
vm.posts.items[arrayid].comment.push is not a function

Comment: use `comments` and not `comment` and remove the line where you try to push to `comment`

Comment: the comments would be better, but the API gives me this subkey `comment`

Comment: hmm than the problem relies in the API, because comment comes as an object and not an array...

Comment: I don't think so. The api just give me a json back. It's `comment: {}`

Comment: Yes, that's an object. `{}` -> object, `[]` -> array

Comment: That was it. I changed the API to give an empty array which makes it much more easy. Thanks, this was the solution :-) Please add it to your Answer to mark it as solution.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure in the array at `arrayid` index an object type should be created.

If not sure, then use the below pattern

```
vm.posts.items[arrayid] = vm.posts.items[arrayid] || {};
vm.posts.items[arrayid].comment = response.plain();
```

The first line will create object only if not yet created yet.

---

**Updated question:**

Looks like even comment should should have an array. So

```
if(!vm.posts.items[arrayid]) {
   vm.posts.items[arrayid] = {};
   vm.posts.items[arrayid].comment = [];
}
vm.posts.items[arrayid].comment.push(response.plain());
```

Comment: @Shanimal Corrected, Thank you :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My console says:
vm.posts.items[arrayid].comment.push is not a function

Comment: Hmm, the above code will create an array, if it is not yet present. If you are using chrome, I would like to suggest clear cache or run in incognito (just to make sure old js is not being used)

Comment: But the array vm.posts.items[arrayid] already exists, what means that the array comment is not being created. How can I check if the comment array in vm.posts.items[arrayid] exists?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to do it in stages - hopefully you won't need all of these but, but...

```
vm.posts = {}
vm.posts.items = []
vm.posts.items[arrayid] = {}
vm.posts.items[arrayid].comment = response.plain();
```

Comment: I think I can't just assign the object, because there will be more than one comment -> there must be an array. Post must be inserted at the end of array.